# How to find value of key if the key is an array?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make the dictionary as coordinates that return colors.

I made a dictionary with the keys as an array, like `[0, 1]`. However, I am unable to get the value through giving the key.

```
dict = {
  key:   [0, 1],
  value: "red"
}

dict[[0, 1]]
```

I expected `dict[[0, 1]]` to give the value "red", however it just says "undefined".

Comment: Is `dict` is an array of objects?

Comment: What exactly are you expecting to return? This is very confusing. And you are confusing property  values with property keys

Comment: Are you sure this is JavaScript?

Comment: I'm trying to make the dictionary as coordinates that return colors.

Comment: Need to be a lot more specific than that about what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: this is a bad idea for reasons explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10173956/how-to-use-array-as-key-in-javascript  essentially you seem to have a misunderstanding of how objects in js work, and are attempting to use an array as a key, which is a very bad idea for reasons in the linked answer.

Comment: @Cloud9c if `dict` is a dictionary, can you provide a sample of that variable with a lot of data on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For using an array as key, you might use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) with the object reference to tha array as key.

This approach does not work for similiar but unequal array.

```js
var map = new Map,
    key = [0, 1],
    value = 'red';

map.set(key, value);

console.log(map.get(key));    // red
console.log(map.get([0, 1])); // undefined
```

For taking a set of coordinates, you could take a nested approach.

```js
function setValue(hash, [x, y], value) {
    hash[x] = hash[x] || {};
    hash[x][y] = value;
}

function getValue(hash, keys) {
    return keys.reduce((o, key) => (o || {})[key], hash);
}

var hash = {},
    key = [0, 1],
    value = 'red';

setValue(hash, key, value);

console.log(getValue(hash, key));
console.log(hash);
```

Or a joined approach with a separator for the values.

```js
var hash = {},
    key = [0, 1].join('|'),
    value = 'red';

hash[key] = value;

console.log(hash[key]);
console.log(hash);
```

Comment: Thanks, I used the joined approach with a separator